# Paypal Framework

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, paypal

I'm trying to set up a paypal-subscription-based website, where people can sign up if they pay a subscription fee trough Paypal.

I'm pretty new to this Paypal IPN system, but I found this plugin which seems to do what I want:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-framework/

Does anyone know what command do I need to send trough the [hashCall()](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/paypal-framework/trunk/paypal-framework.php#L531) function to set up a paypal subscription for the user that's attempting to register? I assume it's something else than `doDirectPayment` and doesn't require all those CC parameters, right?

Answer (score 1):

For subscriptions the method should be `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` and you still have to 
send trough all those CC parameters.

to get a better understanding take a  look at [PayPal API Subscriptions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paypal-api-subscriptions/) which is a bit outdated but the code part of the API call is still relevant.

Comment: but shouldn't credit card processing be done on paypal's website?

Comment: I mean the user filling the CC info, not the actual credit card processing :)

Comment: Well that's the idea behind using API,  the user never leaves your site. If its not what you are after the look at paypal ipn.

Comment: No, I don't want that. It's a WP based site, and if it gets hacked (which apparently is quite common for WP) the site owner would have problems...